# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class ".MyApplication" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.sampledemo.box8demo-1/base.apk"]

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, classnotfoundexception, android-multidex

I have been trying to solve below issue from 3 days.
Problem : Created new module as a library in android project and created aar file using `assembleDebug`.
That aar file i have added in another project as a new module ( dependecies also added ) but after installing the app into the device i am getting below error :

```
6055-26055/com.sampledemo.box8demo E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
        Process: com.sampledemo.box8demo, PID: 26055
        java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate application com.NerdNow.NerdNowApplication: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.NerdNow.NerdNowApplication" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.sampledemo.box8demo-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.sampledemo.box8demo-1/lib/arm64, /vendor/lib64, /system/lib64]]
        at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:580)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4699)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1600(ActivityThread.java:153)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1412)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5441)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:738)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:628)
        Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.NerdNow.NerdNowApplication" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.sampledemo.box8demo-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.sampledemo.box8demo-1/lib/arm64, /vendor/lib64, /system/lib64]]
        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.newApplication(Instrumentation.java:982)
        at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:575)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4699)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1600(ActivityThread.java:153)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1412)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5441)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:738)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:628)
        Suppressed: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.NerdNow.NerdNowApplication
        at dalvik.system.DexFile.defineClassNative(Native Method)
        at dalvik.system.DexFile.defineClass(DexFile.java:226)
        at dalvik.system.DexFile.loadClassBinaryName(DexFile.java:219)
        at dalvik.system.DexPathList.findClass(DexPathList.java:338)
        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:54)
        ... 13 more
        Suppressed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.NerdNow.NerdNowApplication
        at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
        at java.lang.BootClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:781)
        at java.lang.BootClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:841)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:504)
        ... 12 more
        Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Class not found using the boot class loader; no stack trace available
```

I have enabled `multidex` in `gradle` file as well as extended `MultiDexApplication` in `Application` class
Also added `multidex dependecy` in `gradle` file

please help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: disable instant run and try again

Comment: @Divyesh Patel Already disabled, Still no luck

Comment: where is this class:  com.NerdNow.NerdNowApplication

Comment: @DivyeshPatel It is inside the library module. package under com.NerdNow

Comment: did you properly include that project in app module?

Comment: @DivyeshPatel Yes, It is included properly because dummylibraries are working file with less files. It seems like it is multidex related issue.

Comment: did  com.NerdNow.NerdNowApplication is APP module and your main app contains another APP module. maybe it is conflicting.

Comment: @DivyeshPatel No it is not under app module. App module doesnot contains any Application file. Could you please explain why do you think this is conflicting issue?

Comment: just showing NerdNowApplication file. could you check that class code. maybe there is some problem.

Comment: @DivyeshPatel Even removing Application class from module i used to get same exception for Activity. I think this is not specifically related to Application class.

Comment: then must be problem of creating library aar file. try to make via different method

Comment: What are different methods to create aar file? Can you please help me on this

Comment: I do not know much about that. but google surely helps you to find right method

Comment: @DivyeshPatel Sure, i will check that as well. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok Guys, after many try i found that you can not add dependencies on aar files. you have to include jar for each dependencies.